# C++ cout output on RPi 3B

Tags: c++, memory

I have these lines in a C++ program on a RPi 3B:

```
struct bcm2835_peripheral
{
    unsigned long addr_p;
    int mem_fd;
    void *map;
    volatile unsigned int *addr;
};

struct bcm2835_peripheral gpio = {GPIO_BASE};

cout << "1: " << (gpio.addr) << " = " << *(gpio.addr) << endl;
cout << "2: " << (gpio.addr + 7) << " = " << *(gpio.addr + 7) << endl;
```

The two `cout` lines produce the following output:

```
1: 1 = 0
2: 1 = 1735420271
```

The thing that puzzles me is the '1' on the LHS of line 2.  The second `cout` line is adding 7 to `gpio.addr` and so I would expect that the '1' would be '8'.  Clearly the `*(gpio.addr + 7)` is returning a different value, i.e., `(gpio.addr + 7)` is pointing to a different place in the memory.

I cannot see why the code is returning the '1' rather than an '8'.

Comment: Neither can I if they are consecutive lines.

Comment: There must be some other problem. gpio.addr is a 32bit pointer to an unsigned int. Therefore it must be aligned to 4 byte boundaries. 1 is definitely  not at a 4 byte boundary. But even if the first value would be a valid address then adding 7 would actually add 7*4 = 28 to the address. My best guess is that gpio is invalid.

Comment: They are consecutive lines.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how you print pointer addresses with std::cout. Try `printf("1: %p = %u\n", gpio.addr, *(gpio.addr)); printf("2: %p = %u\n", gpio.addr + 7, *(gpio.addr + 7));`

Comment: I edited your question, putting code snippets in the right order instead of describing in free text which statement comes after which. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Related: *[Gobble up the `raspberry-pi` tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315543)* (perhaps the reverse case for this question)

Comment: @PeterMortensen I don't quite understand what you mean. Is it that this question should have been asked on SO with `raspberry-pi` tag? Or do you suggest we get rid of `c++` tag here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ostream` class has no methods to print volatile pointers, and a volatile pointer cannot be converted to a regular pointer without an explicit cast.

However, any pointer can be converted to `bool`: every pointer value is `true` except for NULL which is `false`. This was done to support code which used pointers as conditions, e.g. `if(p) use(p[0]);`. This implicit conversion is exactly what happens here.

Try the following code and see how your pointers are displayed nicely, using `0xabcd` format:

```
std::cout << "1: " << ((int *)gpio.addr) << " = " << *(gpio.addr) << std::endl;
std::cout << "2: " << ((int *)gpio.addr + 7) << " = " << *(gpio.addr + 7) << std::endl;
```

Note that the difference between the two pointers will not be `7` but rather `7*sizeof(int)`, but that's a detail.

Comment: The "detail" here has to do with how *pointer arithmetic* works  (kwasmich alludes to this in a comment too) -- something fundamental the OP should look up and understand ASAP!