# Result of a C++ bit shifting operation

Tags: c++, memory

This is related to a previous post, viz., [C++ cout output on RPi 3B](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59231/c-cout-output-on-rpi-3b)

This code snippet,

```
#define GPIO_SET *(gpio.addr + 7)

struct bcm2835_peripheral
{
    unsigned long addr_p;
    int mem_fd;
    void *map;
    volatile unsigned int *addr;
};

struct bcm2835_peripheral gpio = {GPIO_BASE};

cout << "Before GPIO_SET = 1 << 17: *(gpio.addr + 7) = 0x" << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << *(gpio.addr + 7) << endl;
GPIO_SET = 1 << 17;
cout << "After GPIO_SET = 1 << 17: *(gpio.addr + 7) = 0x" << std::hex << std::setw(8) << std::setfill('0') << *(gpio.addr + 7) << endl;
```

returns,

```
Before GPIO_SET = 1 << 17: *(gpio.addr + 7) = 0x6770696f
After GPIO_SET = 1 << 17: *(gpio.addr + 7) = 0x6770696f
```

I would expect the "after" value to be 0x677**2**696f.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `=` is not additive; I'd expect `0x20000`.  Doesn't explain the problem though.

Comment: What is `GPIO_BASE`? Are you sure you can write there? Did you call `ioremap` to get access? Was the access granted?

Comment: goldilocks, You are correct in that the result should be `0x20000`.

Comment: Dmitry, `GPIO_BASE` is specified as `0x3F200000` as per the specs for the RPi 3B (unchanged from the RPi 2B).  I am sure I can write there as the code actually works in that it turns an LED on and off, cyclically, while running.  The code is modified from a web posting [Low Level Programming of the Raspberry Pi in C](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/15).

Comment: can you check if using printf behaves any differently ?

Comment: Shreyas Murali, Per your suggestion, I tried `printf` and it behaves the same way, viz., the values before and after the shifting operation are the same. It is almost as if the operation `*(gpio.addr + 7) = 1 << 17` is "looking" at a different place in memory than is the request to display / print `*(gpio.addr + 7)`. Clearly the values are being changed since the LED cycles on and off. I have tried a similar operation using Visual Studio 2015 C++ on a Windows machine and it works as expected. Perhaps there is something different about the RPi, maybe a permissions issue.